# To make as a community wiki or not to make as a community wiki?

Tags: discussion

I have something that is bothering me. For my [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28405/what-are-some-of-the-great-or-good-features-that-sharepoint-2007-have-but-howeve), I have multiple good answers and I wish to mark them as correct. (cause I prefer giving 15pt to good answer rather than just voting up, which give them 10pt).

However, it is noted that if I convert my question as a community wiki, this will mean that no one will be able to get the 15pt.

Any ideas on how I can still "reward" those people who give good answer and still able tp continue to receive more good answer from the community?

Answer (score 2):

This would be a great community wiki question!

In general, we try to have people ask questions that can be definitively answered. Polls, lists, or extended discussion questions should be community wiki (or closed.. though we are usually lenient :D ).

Comment: Yes, I wish to make it a community wiki question but my concern is that if it become a wiki question, would there be many people coming out to give their input (as they will not be reward any pt.)

Comment: Right.. this really is a compromise because of the reasoning I gave above. And actually, these types of questions gather a LOT of attention... many of the top voted questions on the site are CW: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes

Answer (score 1):

If you make it a Community Wiki you can't have a definitive answer - that's why it's a CW. You can still upvote to "reward" by upvoting. As Kit says, there is still a good incentive to answer because the CW usually gets more traffic.

There is no way to give more than one answer the thumbs-up - that's just the way the system works. The other good answers will have to make do with upvotes and your encouraging comments. The system is intentionally designed to make you choose the winner. Just pick the best of them - but don't leave it with no answer selected.